# How do I access each element inside vapply or any apply function in R?

Tags: r

```
g <- c(1,2,3,4)
vapply(g, function(x) {

length(x) # This prints out a value of 1. 

# Is there code I can write that will allow me to uniquely access just the second element in this vector?



})
```

I am looking to use vapply specifically, but would like to know how I can access just a single element (any index I want) in the vector that vapply is being acted on. How can I achieve this?

Comment: when you loop over 'g' `vector` there is only one element that is looped.  The `x` is just each element

Comment: I don't think you can. Probably just want to do something like `h <- g[2]` outside of the `vapply` and reference `h` within the function.

Answer (score 2):

The R work around for something like this is usually:

```
g <- c(1,2,3,4)

vapply(seq_along(g), function(i) {
## i is your index number 
## g[i] is the ith element in g
}, double(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

When I have a list or vector of things and I want to `vapply` (or `lapply` or ...) on one or more of them (technically *zero-or-more*), I use a "subset-assignment" technique:

```r
g <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
ind <- 2
### could also be:
# ind <- c(2, 4)
# ind <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE) # logical variant
# ind <- c()                        # empty
g[ind] <- lapply(g[ind], function(x) ...)
```

This does not need to reassign back into `g`, it could be a new vector:

```r
newg <- lapply(g[ind], function(x) ...)
```

where in this case `length(newg)` would be the same as `length(ind)` (or `sum(ind)` if using the logical variant).